# PDF viewer in Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, pdf-viewer

I have a list of documents at server. and want to develop a page where the list of documents will be displayed as hyperlinks in left panel/div and 
while click on a link. the right panel displays the corresponding PDF document from server.

can anybody help me out to develop the same using jquery or javascript?

thanks in advance

i tried below code based on some articles i read
Script :

> ```
> <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
>
> function previewPdf(url, target) 
> {
>
>      var div = document.getElementById(target);
>      var obj = document.createElement("<embed style='width:939px; height:736px;' frameborder='0' src='" + url +"')></embed>");
>      div.appendChild(obj);
> }   
> </script>
> ```

Body :

```
<body style="height: 741px">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">



    <div id="div1" style="float:left; width: 20%; text-align: left; height: 100%; border-width:2px;">
     <button onclick="previewPdf('Documents/Accomodation.pdf','div2')">Accomodation</button>
     <br />
      <button onclick="previewPdf('Documents/Insurance.pdf','div2')">Insurance</button>
     <br />
       <button onclick="previewPdf('Documents/Air Ticket.pdf','div2')">Air Ticket.pdf</button>
     <br />

    </div>

        <div id="div2"  style="float:right;width: 80%; text-align: left; height: 100%; border-color:Maroon">

    </div>


    </form>
</body>
```

but it doesnt replace the 'div2' with the content[pdf].

Comment: what do you mean "the same using jquery or javascript"? reading the docs from the server and rendering the links is done using a server side language. jquery/js are client side. they can manipulate the DOM and interact with the UI. The technologies can work together, but one doesn't replace the other. (unless your talking about node.js as your server language, but I don't think that's the case)

Comment: In pure js/jQuery the question can be a little broad, you can take a look to this project http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ and check out if fits your needs.

Comment: i tried to do same using javascript based on some articles i read. provided the same code above. i am working on asp.net after 4 years hence forgot many things. can you help to find out what wrong i am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript for displaying pdf in html5 format.
You will need edit it as per your requirements.
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a ASP.NET PDF viewer component, then here is how it is done with Gnostice PDFOne .NET.

```
PDFViewer1.ActiveLicense("your-license-key");
PDFViewer1.LoadDocument(Server.MapPath(".") + "\\App_Data\\sample.pdf");
```

[image]

DISCLAIMER: I work for Gnostice.

Comment: Please give me a demo for Gnostice because I am implemented this but not worked it's loading