# how to view original file content with asp.net 3.5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-3.5

i 'm .net developer. now i just want to make feature that user can preview file with one browser dialogue (without downloading it and showing with associating program). sound something interesting.
here i just want to preview any file like PDF, WORD, Text file...

for more reference i include this screen shot:

[image]

here at Attached Document section when user hover file div then two buttons are get appear one is for download and second is for preview when user select preview then one another dialogue opens and it's opens any file which may me Image,text,pdf,word,excel etc. files

Is that possible with asp.net 3.5 with c#

please help me..

Comment: you mean doing like `space` on selected file on mac? to preview in a lightbox?

Comment: You'd be doing well to do this yourself for all those file types, especially if you don't already know where to start. Have a look at a service like http://www.thumbify.me/

Comment: Possible duplication here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298396/pdf-viewer-in-asp-net

Comment: @Pavlo Not a duplicate. Much more detail to this one.

Comment: @RGraham - is there way to make with coding.

Comment: If your server supports previewing of files, you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439719/c-sharp-get-thumbnail-from-file-via-windows-api

Comment: The windows API code pack thumbnail calls are not supported by XP/2003 unfortunately. article says